# ARP сканнирование scapy

Tags: python-3.x, сеть

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, который выполняет ARP сканирование локальной сети. С помощью гугления мной был написан такой код: (здесь Range задается по типу "192.168.0.0/24")

```
import sys
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import srp, Ether, ARP, conf

def scan(Range):

    conf.verb = 0;
    alive,dead = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / ARP( pdst = Range ), 
    timeout = 2, verbose = 0)
    return alive
```

Но возникли 3 проблемы:

1) Скрипт не работает, если по WiFi к сети подключен я сам.

2) Мне необходимо поддерживать 2 способа задания диапазона сканирования:

(192.168.0.0/24) или же (192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.255). Я смог реализовать только первый.

3) Результаты сканирования нестабильны, может найти 2, может найти 4 хоста при неизменном состоянии сети, с чем это может быть связано?

Каким образом можно сделать то что мне нужно? В Питоне новичок.

Comment: 1- старайтесь ограничиваться только одной проблемой в каждом Stack Overflow вопросе (чтобы не только вам вопрос был бы полезен). Если нужно задайте несколько независимых вопросов 2- По какому сетевому интерфейсу вы ожидаете этот код посылает пакеты? Какой интерфейс через wifi работает? Какой вывод `arp` утилита показывает? Какое время по вашему arp кэш хранится? Какая OS? 3- Почему arping() не используете?

Comment: Этот код отправляет пакеты по Ethernet, но я не имею представления, каким образом отправлять пакеты через WiFi, потому что функций, с ним связянных в том же scapy очень много. Утилита arp показывает следующий вывод :
  192.168.0.1             c4-6e-1f-cb-84-a4    
  192.168.0.100         08-d4-0c-c5-86-45   
  192.168.0.103         80-e6-50-46-e7-53    
  192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff

В то время как мой код находит от 1 до 2 случайных хостов из этого списка. 
OS - Windiws 10 x64

Comment: Какой интерфейс через wifi работает? - Не смог выяснить
Какое время по вашему arp кэш хранится? - Не смог выяснить
Почему arping() не используете? - arping() выдает такое же поведение, собственно мой код отчасти взят из ее реализации

Comment: ваш код получает ответы, если параметр `iface` правильный на моей машине (и не получает, если неправильный). Если не знаете «как список сетевых интерфейсов получить на Windows» задайте *отдельный* вопрос. Начните с `get_if_list()`.